# Total count in a Table using macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table as mentioned in Input Table and needed output as mentioned in Output Table required. I used COUNTIFS but its not giving the result as expected. It seems for this need to write macro. Can you please help.

Input Table:
[image]
Output Table required:
[image]

Comment: Please provide usable data and expected results.

Comment: Please see below table as expected result.

Phase Total Count of C Total Count of O Total Count of P
1 7 6 3
3 7 5 4

Comment: The output should be Total Number of C, O and P from Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr based on Category Phase 1 or 2.
Which means Total Number of C for Phase 1 occured in the Month of Jan, Feb, Mar and Apr.

Total Number of C for Phase 2 occured in the Month of Jan, Feb, Mar and Apr.

Total Number of O for Phase 1 occured in the Month of Jan, Feb, Mar and Apr. and so on....

Comment: No need for VBA, just a simple formula:`=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$E$9=B$11)*($A$2:$A$9=$A12))` (assuming the result table starts in a11)

Comment: @BrakNicku I just copied your formula in A11 - =SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$E$9=B$11)*($A$2:$A$9=$A12))  but it's not working.. it's giving 0 result in A11... also i see B11 and A12 in the formula... is it correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use an array formula:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Michael for your quick support.